# Can an extended partition originally be either a primary partition or a logical partition?

Tags: partition

I heard  that a partition used to house  logical partitions is called an extended partition.

Can an extended partition originally be either a primary partition or a logical partition? Or must an extended partition originally be a primary partition, but not a logical partition?

In other words, if you have an extended partition wherein you have several logical partitions, can you make one logical partition become an extended partition to create logical partitions recursively?

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be referring to the MS-DOS partitioning scheme as was used on PCs before GPT. Though most Unix-like systems understand that partitioning scheme, it's off-topic here as you're not asking about anything specific to Unix or Linux.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, IMO this is not off-topic because partitioning is done on every linux installation.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the so called "MS-DOS" partitioning scheme should be called "Linux" partitioning scheme, since Linux has the most complete and best documented implementation of it, and other x86 Unices were not able to use logical partitions until fairly recently (a well-known bsd variant had a ridiculously broken implementation of it until 8 years or so ago).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the partitions logic:

1. You may have maximum of 4 primary or extended partitions on disk (MBR disks)
2. You can have only one extended partition
3. If you want more you must have extended partition and inside
   this partition create logical partitions.
4. Think about extended partition as container of logical partitions.
5. You can't have filesystem on extended partition.

Maybe this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition) can give you more information about the subject

EDIT1: You can't convert logical to extended (and continue recursively) because you have already one extended (where this logical is created)

Comment: Can an extended partition originally be either a primary partition or a logical partition? Or must an extended partition originally be a primary partition, but not a logical partition?

Comment: It can be primary, but "converted" to extended. Usually this is done by destroy the primary and create extended. And you can have only one extended on disk

Comment: Must a logical partition reside in an extended partition? In other words, if there exists a logical partition, does that mean there is already an extended partition?

Comment: @tim, correct. Logical must be in extended

Comment: I recommend not to use MBR partitioning, and use GPT instead. It's so much simpler: there is just one type of partition, and there is no practical limit on how many partitions a disk can hold. I even recommend using GPT on a non-EFI machine, you just need a small BIOS boot partition for Grub.

Comment: @JohanMyréen, why do you think most of the people will need more than 15 partitions? Moreover using wisely LVM you can avoid most of the MBR limitations in sense of number of partitions

Comment: @JohanMyréen Nice to know. I didn't know the differences between primary, logical, extended partitions don't exist in GPT.  By "non-EFI" do you mean   BIOS for example? How do I know if a computer uses EFI or non-EFI, and use MBR or GPT?

Comment: @RomeoNinov It's not the number of partitions, but the trouble handling the different types of partitions, primary, extended, logical, and the funny numbering that comes with it. Why bother, when GPT provides a much cleaner solution. In addition, you can't use MBR partitions on a disk larger than 2 TB.

Comment: @JohanMyréen, I found no problem handle them. And with please help/teach others about :)

Comment: Where does that 15 partition limit come from? Do you have any reference? Last time when I had a contentious discussion about that (some 10 or 15 years ago), I had checked and neither windows nor linux was enforcing such a limit.

Comment: @mosvy, I found this number in my memory. Maybe I am wrong...

Comment: You should remove that point (4.), since it's detracting from your answer -- all the other points are basically correct (that there's only one extended partition, that all logical partitions are contained inside it, and that you can't use the extended partition directly).